# How to define macros when having multiple files?

Tags: c, macros

Let's say I have a header file:

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

int sum(int a, int b);

#endif
```

and I want to define a macro `#define A 100` inside the header file so that it can be used by multiple c files whenever I need it. Can I place the definition above the sum function or there is another better way to do it?

Comment: Yes, put the macro in a header, then include it wherever you need it. *"Can I place the definition above the sum function"* Above or below, doesn't matter.

Comment: Did you try it? Did you get any problems?

Comment: Header files declare the public API of a module or library, only rarely a bunch of otherwise unrelated constants. Think carefully about your architecture. A header file included in many source files generates a possibly complicated dependency. Put this constant in an appropriate header file, not just any, if necessary, write a separated one. Think about what part sets this requirement, what part is responsible.

Comment: @thebusybee I think your commentis too much for a comment and too little for an answer. At least before finding out which problems OP encountered while trying to achieve what.

Comment: @Yunnosch Of course, you're right, and I hesitated before clicking "Add". But to my big frustration far too many junior developers (and too many seniors, too!) have no idea about software architecture and software design. Projects fail in the beginning, not at the end. So I thought, well, just give the OP something to think about. HTH. ;-) But details of this are OT for this question and subject of our handcraft, software development.

Comment: @4386427 Sorry for not responding, my bad. I did try it and did not encoutner any errors!